# How can I animate a SVG Text element to skew relative to a polygon

Tags: animation, text, svg

Okay so I have a polygon, and I want to skew text, so it looks like the polygon contains the text. It is probably easier to just show what I mean. Below is an example, I have written a method to dynamicly manipulate the polygon vertices. This animation is to show a page folding over in a book.

http://jsfiddle.net/sdjqw/

Anyway, as seen in the example, I need to skew the text relative to blue polygon (at the moment it is only clipped based on the blue polygons position). So the blue page shows what is n it correctly. If this is not possible, are there any good alternatives?

On a sidenote, in this example i have applied shading to the blue element, but it appears on 3 sides, any simple way to make it only appear on a single side?

I have also been looking at  to just rotate and move the text, I think this could possibly work, but is not my ideal solution.

Comment: I would use a [`transform=()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) attribute on the text or a wrapping group. If you wrap your 'page' and text in the same group, you'll only have to animate the transform in one location.

Comment: …but it looks like your blue page isn't even skewing, just rotating.

Comment: Yes at the moment, it is only rotating, hence the question (rotating doesn't look right).